# REST query with two lists

Tags: jquery, rest, sharepoint

Is it possible to query two list in the same time?

url: http://sites.com/url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘List1')

url: http://sites.com/url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘List1' and 'List2')

Answer (score 1):

### Linked Lists

For [Linked Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728095%28v=office.14%29.aspx) you can specify that the request returns projected fields from other lists and the values of Lookups. To do this, specify the field name in both the `$select` and `$expand` query options.

Example

Assume the following linked lists - `Employee` and `Company`, where  `Employee` list contains  Lookup column to `Company` list:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Employee')/items?$select=Title,Company/ID,Company/Title&$expand=Company/ID
```

### Regular Lists

You need to perform two request since batching is not supported in REST API.

Example:

The following example demonstrates how to perform read operation for list items

```
function getListItems(listName, siteurl, success, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: siteurl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.results);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Please follow an article [Manipulating list items in SharePoint Hosted Apps using the REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx) for a more details.

Then you could read list items from `Employee` and `Company` as demonstrated below:

```
getListItems('Employee','https://contoso.sharepoint.com',
   function(employeeItems){
       console.log(employeeItems);

       getListItems('Company','https://contoso.sharepoint.com',
          function(companyItems){
            console.log(companyItems);
          },
          function(error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          }
       );
   },
   function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to batch your query - you may use javascript client side object model. In that case when you do context.ExecuteQueryAsync() - you query all you defined before at one request.

If you need do it via REST - you can simple do two query async, they will execute in parallel.

Comment: @stockDevelopers, in javascript all queries to web services are async by default. You may use jquery $ajax, mquery $ajax or sharepoint requestexecutor for web service requests - it will be async.